# How to get WPtouch working?

Tags: plugin-wptouch

I bought WPtouch Pro few days back and finished the designing and developing on localhost. Now I want to upload it on my online live hosting to get a mobile version of my website on a subdomain.

I want the mobile version of website on a subdomain like `m.mywebsite.com` for the same content. Do I need to install WordPress separately on a subdomain, install WPtouch Pro there and build a separate version of my website? Should I just copy the WordPress files from my root directory on main domain and paste it to the subfolder (subdomain)? Should I just install the WPtouch Pro on my existing WordPress installation?

Comment: [WP Touch PRO](http://www.bravenewcode.com/support/) has a dedicated support forum, that you can enter as customer - at least if you _really purchased it_ ...

Answer (score 2):

There is [this very old](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wptouch-call-mobile-version-with-direct-url#post-2108410) post on wordpress.org that I think is the answer to your concerns.

From the plugin author (*ten months ago*):

> Using a sub-domain is not supported at this time. However, if you mean that you'd like to do your own redirection/detection, you can use one of the many Javascript and PHP redirects out there.

Answer (score 1):

WPTouch works by detecting the device which is loading the website, and serving the WPTouch theme for mobile devices, and leaving the website theme alone for all other devices.

You don't need to install it on a separate sub-domain, it will magically intercept the request from the mobile device and serve the mobile theme to mobile devices only.

Comment: Thanks Steve, but the client want his website to appear something like as m.google.com or m.facebook.com
Well, honestly speaking, i never worked on a mobile version of website before, it's the very first time. So, do i need a separate installation of wordpress on sub-domain? the client want his mobile version to look totally different from PC desktop version, i mean all the pages of website will be different in looks and feels e.g. Home, About Us and Contact Us.